# ASP.Net MVC (2) - Getting ModelMetadata from a View without a custom template

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I (if possible) get to the ModelMetadata from a view without creating a custom template for the given Model's property?

Traditionally, I have just made a new template and altered the template using the ViewData.ModelMetadata.IsRequired (for example).  However, I'm looking for how to access this information in the base view and not within a specific editor template.

In terms of why I don't want to go the editor template route - I have a form where I need better control to the markup in terms of attributes on the input elements. EditorTemplates work decent but having a specialized template and ensuring additional ViewData are set to fulfill the attribute values isn't clean in my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should give you access:

```
<%
    var metadata = ViewData.ModelMetadata;
%>
```

You may checkout how the [default templates are implemented](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html). It might give you some additional ideas.

Comment: That doesn't really help me since I'm not seeing how (or which property of) ViewData.ModelMetadata can provide me if Model.Name (for example) has the [Required] attribute on it or not.

Comment: @JamesEggers, that's easy, once you get the metadata of the model you can get everything about this model and its children (in terms of metadata). So for example if you are inside a template for the `Name` property all you need is `var isRequired = ViewData.ModelMetadata.IsRequired;` => which will tell you if the Name property is decorated with the `[Required]` attribute. If you are in the context of your parent view model simply: `var isRequired = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression<MyViewModel, string>(x => x.Name, ViewData).IsRequired;`

Comment: Do you know of an alternative to "FromLambdaExpression" that works in 3.5?  Otherwise would be perfect.

Comment: @JamesEggers, `FromLambdaExpression`, works perfectly fine in .NET 3.5.

Comment: I was attempting to use it as an instance method and not a static.  Works great.  Thanks!