# MVC4 input field placeholder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Does `MVC4` by default support `placeholders` for generated input fields? I didn't found anything so I am trying to implement my own but unfortunately `Prompt = "E-Mail"` is not passed to `ViewData.ModelMetadata.Watermark` while generating control. Why?

Model

```
public class LogOnModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "E-Mail", Prompt = "E-Mail")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { placeholder = ViewData.ModelMetadata.Watermark })
```

I get html code where `placeholder` tag do not has any text

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-regex="Please enter a valid e-mail address" data-val-required="The E-Mail field is required." id="Email" name="Email" placeholder="" type="text" value="" class="valid">
```

Comment: This question is the same as : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841233/modelmetadata-watermark-and-mvc-view-models. The answer proposed there is to used `EditorFor` instead of `TextBoxFor` or to use inline placeholder...

Comment: Hmmm, sorry, I meant *templated* EditorFor (that means you placed it in the special directory "EditorTemplates" and point its model to your field...).

Answer (score 47, accepted):

An alternative to using a plugin is using an editor template. What you need to do is to create a template file in `Shared\EditorTemplates` folder and call it `String.cshtml`. Then put this in that file:

```
@Html.TextBox("",ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, 
    new { placeholder = ViewData.ModelMetadata.Watermark })
```

Then use it in your view like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m=>Model.UnitPercent)
```

The downside, this works for properties of type `string`, and you will have to create a template for each `type` that you want support for a watermark.

Comment: I did that but @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Email) never call and use Shared\EditorTemplates\String.cshtml. Any ideas why?

Comment: I found the problem, the file should be EmailAddress.schtml in my case because my model property type is  [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]

Comment: You got it! Just remember that's the downside of it.

Answer (score 41):

I did so

Field in model:

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "User name")]
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

Razor:

```html
<li>
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(n => n.UserName)})
</li>
```

Comment: This is nice and simple. Didn't require any extra templates and fetches the Display attribute for the ViewModel property nice and simple.

Comment: This will double-escape the text provided in DisplayName - no problem with the given example, but if you add french accents for example, this will be a problem.

Answer (score 27):

Of course it does:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email, new { @placeholder = "Email" })
```

Comment: I would like to use MVC approach.

Comment: I see, i misunderstood your question. Maybe an editor template like von.v suggested would be a solution. See also this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824124/html5-placeholders-with-net-mvc-3-razor-editorfor-extension

Answer (score 13):

You can easily add Css class, placeholder , etc. as shown below:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder="Name" })
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Most straightforward solution IMO. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

This works:

```
@Html.TextBox("name", null,  new { placeholder = "Text" })
```

Comment: just tell me one thing why we used null before it.

Answer (score 6):

There are such of ways to Bind a Placeholder to View:

**1) With use of MVC Data Annotations:**

Model:

```
[Required]
[Display(Prompt = "Enter Your First Name")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

Razor Syntax:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { placeholder = @Html.DisplayNameFor(n => n.UserName)})
```

**2) With use of MVC Data Annotations But with DisplayName:**

Model:

```
[Required]
[DisplayName("Enter Your First Name")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

Razor Syntax:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { placeholder = @Html.DisplayNameFor(n => n.UserName)})
```

**3) Without use of MVC Data Annotation (recommended):**

Razor Syntax:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @placeholder = "Enter Your First Name")
```

Comment: `placeholder = @Html.DisplayNameFor...` will double-escape the displayName text, problematic in the case of french accents for example.

Answer (score 4):

By default, it does not. However, you can use the [MVCHtml5Toolkit](https://nuget.org/packages/MVCHtml5Toolkit) NuGet package that has HTML helpers that can output HTML5. For your example, after installing the toolkit you can then use the following HTML helper call:

```
@Html.Html5TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, InputTypes.InputType.Email)
```

This will output the following HTML:

```
<input id="Email" name="Email" placeholder="E-Mail" type="Email" value="">
```

As can be seen, the placeholder is now correctly rendered.

Answer (score 4):

The correct solution to get the `Prompt` value in a non-templated control context is:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, 
    new { placeholder = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(m => m.Email, ViewData).Watermark }
)
```

This will also *not* double-escape the watermark text.

Comment: This is the correct answer I was looking for. Thank you! It also works inside a kendo popup custom template.

Answer (score -1):

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control",@placeholder = "Name"  })
```

Comment: This is a very low quality post. Please improve. Right now it is a code dump.

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
@Html.TextbBoxFor(x=>x.Email,new { @placeholder=@viewBag.email}
```

If this possible or else what could be the way

Comment: It is not Quality answer . Please improve Your answer