# How do I clear a text EditorFor

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

I have an element on a Razor page like this:

```
<td>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FreeTextName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    </div>
</td>
```

When the page first renders it has hint text in it like 'Enter name to search for here'

I would like for this text to disappear when the user clicks into the field so I wrote a little script like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#FreeTextSwitchId').focusin(
        $('#FreeTextName').val("")
        )
</script>
```

But now my page renders with the hint test gone. I know it is the script doing it because if I do something like this: `$('#FreeTextName').val("test")` then 'test' shows up instead of the hint text.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Use your `@Html.EditorFor()` like that:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FreeTextName, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Now you have given a class in your `@Html.EditorFor()` i.e `.form-control`. Use your class in your script. Do the script like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('.form-control').on('blur click', function(){ 
        $(this).val("");
    });

</script>
```

Moreover you can also use `placeholder="Your Hint"` attribute in your `@Html.EditorFor()` i.e:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FreeTextName, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder="Enter name to search for here" })
```

It is an html input type="textbox" attribute that automatically adds default text to textbox as default hint so that the user can understand what should be given in this textbox. For this you don't need to use any script.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to do a watermark??? you can use the "placeholder" attribute in HTML5

```html
 <input placeholder="example text" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a placeholder into the input. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/naeqgnd3/

`<input placeholder="'Enter name to search for here" />`

The text will disappear when the user types in the input.

Answer (score 0):

I actually decided to go with the top answer in [MVC4 input field placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16031385/mvc4-input-field-placeholder) since I was using MVC4: