# How to make glyphicon as @placeholder in mvc @Html.TextBoxFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to make glyphicon as Placeholder in MVC something like:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control",@placeholder= @"<span class=input-group-addon style=width:4px;><i class=glyphicon glyphicon-user></i></span>" } )
```

but i got no luck.

I've been searched some possible solution no luck.

Is it possible to View  `glyphicon` using `MVC @Html.TextBoxFor`?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27628133/asp-net-mvc5-font-awesome-in-placeholder?rq=1

Comment: That solution has been searched already, the glyphicon is outside the input box

Comment: Thanks @Wheels73

Comment: Also no luck @Wheels73.. it's treated as string.